# How do I make a gdbus call from udev?

Tags: udev, d-bus, brightness

I am trying to set the display brightness through udev so that I can have different brightness levels on battery and mains power. The following gdbus call works from the command line:-

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen Brightness '<int32 65>'
```

However, if I have the same thing in a udev rules file:-

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="0", RUN+="gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen Brightness '<int32 65>'"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="1", RUN+="gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen Brightness '<int32 100>'"
```

then triggering the udev rule with `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=power_supply` does nothing. How can I make this gdbus call work through udev?

Comment: `udev` scripts run in a restricted environment and **shouldn't** (and often **can't**) do complicated things (like using sockets for DBUS calls). Try to get acpi events or input events (check with `evtest` if power events appear on a input device) instead.

Comment: I don't get anything on `evtest`. How do I test for ACPI events? (I'm trying this on Fedora, where ACPI packages aren't installed by default, but I can install them if needed.)

Comment: First of all, don't try this at home or office.... Even if you want to try, Before calling from udev, you should make sure that `dbus-deamon` is up and also `org.gnome.SettingDaemon.Power` D-Bus service is up and running and can you also check whether this service is D-Bus activatable?

Comment: The `gdbus` call works from the command line, as I've mentioned in the post. It doesn't work through udev even when `dbus-daemon` and `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power` are up, which is what I gather people here are trying to emphasize. I basically want to adjust the brightness according to power plug-in events, and also on start-up/login, and inform GNOME of the adjustment. I understand that D-Bus services will only be available after a certain time on start-up, but I don't know how to make the calls on power events.

Comment: Not sure about Fedora, but try to find a package with `acpi_listen`. Googling finds Fedora has [acpid](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Power_Management_Guide/acpid.html), so you can set up rules.